# Passing function arguments via a shortcode

Tags: functions, shortcode

I have a simple WP_Query that displays posts:

```
<?php
function vertical_posts( $title, $category, $num_of_posts ) { ?>
    <section class="vertical-posts">
        <h2 class="title"><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
        <div class="post-grid">
            <?php
            $args = array('category_name'  => $category, 'posts_per_page' => $num_of_posts);
            $query = new WP_Query($args);
            if ($query->have_posts()) {
                while ($query->have_posts()) {
                    $query->the_post();
                    ?>
                    <article class="post">
                        <a class="post-thumbnail" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
                            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('landscape-medium-1x'); ?>" alt="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_post_thumbnail_id(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ); ?>" loading="lazy">
                        </a>
                        <header class="entry-header">
                            <?php the_title('<h3 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink()) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h3>'); ?>
                            <div class="entry-meta">
                                <?php
                                posted_on();
                                posted_by();
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </header>
                    </article>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            else {
                echo '<p>Please add some posts.</p>';
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php
}
```

I'm calling this throughout my theme like so:

```
<?php vertical_posts( 'Answers', 'answers', 4 ); ?>
```

I'd like to have the ability to call this function with a shortcode in the block or classic editor.

I've created the shortcode via my functions:

```
function register_shortcodes(){
    add_shortcode('vertical-posts', 'vertical_posts');
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

Is it possible to pass the function arguments to my shortcode?

I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
[vertical-posts 'Answers', 'answers', 4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a new function for my shortcode:

```
<?php
function shortcode_posts( $atts ) { 
    $sc = shortcode_atts( array(
        'title' => 'Answers',
        'category' => 'answers',
        'num_of_posts' => 4
    ), $atts );
    ?>
    <section class="vertical-posts">
        <h2 class="title"><?php echo $sc['title']; ?></h2>
        <div class="post-grid">
            <?php
            $args = array('category_name'  => $sc['category'], 'posts_per_page' => $sc['num_of_posts']);
            $query = new WP_Query($args);
            if ($query->have_posts()) {
                while ($query->have_posts()) {
                    $query->the_post();
                    ?>
                    <article class="post">
                        <a class="post-thumbnail" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
                            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('landscape-medium-1x'); ?>" alt="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_post_thumbnail_id(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ); ?>" loading="lazy">
                        </a>
                        <header class="entry-header">
                            <?php the_title('<h3 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink()) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h3>'); ?>
                            <div class="entry-meta">
                                <?php
                                posted_on();
                                posted_by();
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </header>
                    </article>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            else {
                echo '<p>Please add some posts.</p>';
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php
}
```

Here's how I register the shortcode:

```
function register_shortcodes(){
    add_shortcode('posts', 'shortcode_posts');
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

I'd then call the shortcode like so:

```
[posts title="Answers" category="answers" num_of_posts="4"]
```

There's a [great article from Kinsta](https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-shortcodes/) which goes into detail about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely pass arguments to your shortcode, but not in the method you described.  Please see the Shortcode API (https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Your shortcode with arguments will look more like:

[vertical_posts label=Answers category=answers number=4]